# Instagram API: Replying to Someone's Post?

Tags: api, post, comments, instagram, reply

I've been using the API to reply get media from posts using a hashtag. I've been able to respond something like a "thank you" but it only works if it's towards my own account.

If I respond to my own account I get an ID back and the comment is successful, if I respond to someone else I get back this message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '{POST-ID}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "{fbtrace_id}"
  }
}
```

The POST method I'm using is: `{POST-ID}/comments?message=thank you`

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Does the token you use include all required permissions to access POST-ID?

Comment: The current permissions my token has are:
pages_show_list,
instagram_basic,
instagram_manage_comments,
public_profile...

Anything I might be missing?

Also, I believe the POST-ID is right considering I'm able to extract media_urls and stuff like that from any user's posts.

Comment: I am not sure why you getting this error, maybe check your access token, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFTr7tLXJZ4. this guy got the same error at 15:52.

Comment: After changing the code from "comments?message" to "replies?message" I now get an "Unsupported post request" error. I think it's because the latter is for replying to comments and requires a COMMENT-ID instead of a POST-ID, but I want to comment a post, which is different. My current script works just like I want to but only works if I'm replying to my own account, and I believe the issue lies somewhere in the permissions territory like you said earlier... I just don't know what I'm missing.